# Julia 0.4 cannot found modules in local path on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, julia

I have a file called `ModuleName.jl` in a local directory. I believe this file contains a valid module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
module ModuleName
...
end
```

When trying to load the module `julia -e "using ModuleName"` I get:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: ModuleName not found in path
in require at ./loading.jl:233
in process_options at ./client.jl:284
in _start at ./client.jl:411
```

All works right with julia 0.3.11 in the local directory, but it fails with Julia 0.4.0. I use 64bit Ubuntu 14.04. How can I fix this?

Comment: what's your current working dir? where is your module?  `using` implicitly calls [`require`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=require#Base.require), "When searching for files, `require` first looks in the current working directory." that might be the reason.

Comment: @GnimucKey ModuleName.jl is located in my working dir. And julia 0.3.11 loads it successfully.

Comment: @GnimucKey Is `require` deprecated in julia 0.4.0? [Source code of `require`.](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.4/base/require.jl)
Where can I find implementation of `using`?

Comment: i can't find the implementation of `using` too. the deprecated `require(ASCIIString)` works fine when running `require("ModuleName")`.

Comment: you can find the new `require()` in `loading.jl`. i've just checked out that the function `find_in_path()` works well. take a look at this related [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12695).

Comment: @GnimucKey `requre(:ModuleName)` fails too. find_in_path() works well for  me.

Comment: Is there any way to import files from the working directory? This seems like a fundamental feature. Something like 'import file' in python. find_in_path() is showing as undefined in julia .4.3. Trying to write a julia script, but no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

currently(v0.4.0), `using` doesn't look in the current working directory. but the good news is you can use something like `using .ModuleName` to load modules in CWD as long as issue [#4600](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4600) is implemented(before v0.5.0).

this undocumented change from v0.3 to v0.4 is due to [this commit](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/75ab3602fcaf224dfcc550dad684125936e4bc44). if you want to make `using` behave as it in v0.3. you can change this [line](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ef460740f5c1177339086b79c7008454278159c7/base/loading.jl#L31) to `find_in_path(name)` and recompile julia from the modified source code.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other suggestions, I have had success by setting the environment variable for the Julia load path (`JULIA_LOAD_PATH`) to include the local directory. In other words, running Julia with:

```
JULIA_LOAD_PATH=. julia
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are developign some code, this works best for me: create a `main.jl` at the root of your package/module folder. it contains

`include("your-source.jl")`

and maybe also

`include("your-tests.jl")`

you can then just open a julia session in your console, work on "your-source.jl", and just send this line into the terminal whenever you want to try it out.
Once you are done you can add the package onto the load path.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `using ModuleName`, Julia looks in paths that already defined in `LOAD_PATH` constant.

To check contents of `LOAD_PATH` constant simply call it:

```
julia>LOAD_PATH 
2-element Array{ByteString,1}:
 "C:\\Users\\AliReza\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-0.4.0\\local\\share\\julia\\site\\v0
.4"
 "C:\\Users\\AliReza\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-0.4.0\\share\\julia\\site\\v0.4"
```

And what is your current working directory?

```
julia> pwd()
"C:\\Users\\AliReza\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-0.4.0"
```

You can `include` a file related to current location if it exists:

```
julia> include("missedModule.jl")
ERROR: could not open file C:\Users\AliReza\AppData\Local\Julia-0.4.0\missedModu
le.jl
 in include at boot.jl:261
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:304
```

You will get another Error if you want to load a Module that isn't exist in `LOAD_PATH`

```
julia> using LocalModule
ERROR: ArgumentError: LocalModule not found in path
 in require at loading.jl:233
```

If `LocalModule.jl` is a file in local working directory, and you want to load it by `using`, push current path to `LOAD_PATH`, `push!(LOAD_PATH, pwd())`, now it's possible to load LocalModule, by `using`, from working directory.

Comment: I checked LOAD_PATH in Ubuntu (0.4.0) and OS X (0.3.11). Both don't have local path. But `using` works in OS X and do not in Ubuntu. Has Julia changed behaviour between these versions?